# Control Charts in Python

Tags: python, charts, pandas

I currently use R routinely for [statistical process control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_process_control). With this I can produce [control charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart) such as [EWMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMA_chart), Shewhart, [CUSUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUSUM) and [GAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model) / [Loess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) smoothing.

Does anyone know of the best way to do these types of charts using Python? I initially looked at [`scikits.timeseries`](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/) but it has been canned to contribute to [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

I had a look at pandas and although it does have EWMA functionality, I need a little bit more.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just found [this package](https://launchpad.net/python-spc/+milestone/0.3) that has not been updated in a while, but works so far in Python 2.7.3 (on 64-bit Windows 7, using pretty up-to-date supporting packages):

```
In [1]: import spc
In [2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [3]: x = [25,19,14,17,25,39,49,6,11,19,13,26,24,32,14,19]
In [4]: cc = spc.Spc(x, spc.CHART_X_MR_X)
In [5]: cc.get_chart()
In [6]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Looks like the 6th point is outside the upper control limit...

```
In [7]: cc.get_violating_points()
Out[7]: {'1 beyond 3*sigma': [6]}
```

The package is basically a single **init**.py file that is only a few hundred source lines, and looks to implement more than a dozen charts, including CUSUM.

Lastly, there is a github project worth keeping an eye on: https://github.com/bwghughes/controlchart