# Multiple colors in the one graph in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to change the color of the graph about a certain threshold in python Matplotlib ?

```
plt.plot(temp)
plt.plot((0, len(temp)), (100, 100), 'b-')
plt.ylabel('Some data')
plt.show()
```

where temp contains some data
The final image looks soomething like this:
[image]

Now is it possible to display the data above this line ( 100 in this case) in some other color ?

Comment: Is it important that the data will be as a continuous graph? Why not just plot the data as points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Is it possible to change line color in a plot if exceeds a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121773/python-is-it-possible-to-change-line-color-in-a-plot-if-exceeds-a-specific-rang)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use masked array to draw multiple lines. Here is an example:

Find the intersection points between curve and the threshold line, and insert the points to the original data. Then you can call `plot()` twice with masked array:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

def threshold_plot(x, y, th, fmt_lo, fmt_hi):
    idx = np.where(np.diff(y > th))[0]
    x_insert = x[idx] + (th - y[idx]) / (y[idx+1] - y[idx]) * (x[idx+1] - x[idx])
    y_insert = np.full_like(x_insert, th)

    xn, yn = np.insert(x, idx+1, x_insert), np.insert(y, idx+1, y_insert)

    mask = yn < th
    pl.plot(np.ma.masked_where(mask, xn), np.ma.masked_where(mask, yn), fmt_hi, lw=2)

    mask = yn > th
    pl.plot(np.ma.masked_where(mask, xn), np.ma.masked_where(mask, yn), fmt_lo)
    pl.axhline(th, color="black", linestyle="--")

x = np.linspace(0, 3 * np.pi, 50)
y = np.random.rand(len(x))
threshold_plot(x, y, 0.7, "b", "r")
```

the result:

[image]