# Pandas plot - how to change color above an y limit

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code giving me a plot :

```
    ax = z['%s-01'%(year):'%s-12'%(year)].groupby('d').count().plot()
    ax.set_ylim(0, 800)
    ax.set_xlim(pd.Timestamp('%i-01-01'%year), pd.Timestamp('%i-12-31'%year))
```

here is the result :

[image: how to change the color above y=100 ??]

I would like to change the color above y=100, to have it red for example. 
[image]
Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: Your question has already been asked and answered:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121773/python-is-it-possible-to-change-line-color-in-a-plot-if-exceeds-a-specific-rang