# Changing color and linestyle when plot exceeds a specific threshold in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the following function to change the line color in matplotlib if it exceeds a specific threshold (it is copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30125761/11303808):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

def threshold_plot(ax, x, y, threshv, color, overcolor):
    cmap = ListedColormap([color, overcolor])
    norm = BoundaryNorm([np.min(y), threshv, np.max(y)], cmap.N)

    points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

    lc = LineCollection(segments, linestyles=['solid', 'dashed'], cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    lc.set_array(y)

    ax.add_collection(lc)
    ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))
    ax.set_ylim(np.min(y)*1.1, np.max(y)*1.1)
    return lc


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 3 * np.pi, 500)
y = np.sin(x)

lc = threshold_plot(ax, x, y, .75, 'k', 'r')
ax.axhline(.75, color='k', ls='--')
lc.set_linewidth(3)
lc.set_linestyles(['-', '--'])
plt.show()
```

Now I would like to change the linestyle in addition to the color of the line. Therefore I have added `lc.set_linestyles(['-', '--'])` but it does not work.

How am I supposed to adjust the function?

Comment: Did you try to use the `linestyles` argument?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes, I tried `linestyles=['-','--']`, but did not work.

Comment: Ok, so would you mind showing the attempt inside the questions then? Else how should anyone know where you did wrong?

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question.

Comment: Wait, you have 500 points, that means 499 line segments. But only 2 linestyles? That sure can't work. Which linestyle should the remaining 497 segments have?

Comment: Thanks for this hint. What do I have to change in my code to get the result that I want?

Comment: As said above, you will need to supply a list of 499 linestyles.