# How to get masked array to color whole segment in pyplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've been looking to have my time series colored red when my y-value exceeds a threshold (in this case 30).

I went through and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121773/python-is-it-possible-to-change-line-color-in-a-plot-if-exceeds-a-specific-rang) which gives 2 main suggestions: either using masked arrays or building a color map by segment. I return a key error[0] when I try reworking the color map solution, but when I try using masked arrays, I get the following:

[image]

This is very close to what I need, but I can't seem to find a way to color the whole line above the threshold, just the segments. How can I get the whole line to appear red above the threshold line?

Here is my code I used to generate the plot:

```
#Note: This isn't my source data, but will show the same effect
ut9_ffwi = [2, 15, 14, 28, 40, 49, 27, 36, 24, 12]
ut9_time = range(0, 10, 1)

threshold = 30
ut9_ffwi = np.ma.array(ut9_ffwi)
ut201_ffwi = np.ma.array(ut201_ffwi)
mask = ma.masked_where(ut9_ffwi <= threshold, ut9_ffwi)

# Plot
plt.plot(ut9_time, ut9_ffwi)
# Highlight values above 30
plt.plot(ut9_time, mask, 'r', linewidth=3.2)
# Plot a horizontal line for threshold
plt.axhline(y = threshold, color='r', linestyle='-')
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.legend(['FFWI Data', 'Threshold'])
```

Comment: the issue is that it is detecting data values above 30 and changing the lines between them to red, you would need some kind of interpolation to generate new points where the line crosses 30 in order to get nice continuous red.  not sure how to post an answer but figured this might help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow along with the guide to a [Multicolored Line](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_MulticoloredLine.html). The trick as pointed out in the comments is to interpolate using a very fine grid, that way you can stop the segments relatively close to your cutoff. The sample here uses your variables, but is a bit noisier to really illustrate the point.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

np.random.seed(410112)
ut9_ffwi = np.random.randint(0, 50, 100)
ut9_time = range(len(ut9_ffwi))
```

---

```
# Interpolate using a very fine grid
Nfine = 500
x = np.linspace(ut9_time[0], ut9_time[-1], len(ut9_time)*Nfine)
y = np.interp(x, ut9_time, ut9_ffwi)

# Now to color the segments
cmap = ListedColormap(['b', 'r'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 30, np.inf], cmap.N)

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
lc.set_array(y)
lc.set_linewidth(3)
plt.gca().add_collection(lc)

plt.xlim(x.min(), x.max())
plt.ylim(y.min(), y.max())

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you set `Nfine=1` then it will plot as if there were no interpolation to a finer grid, and you will see the segments bleed across the boundary. The bigger `Nfine` is the sharper the boundary will be for noisy data, though at the price of plotting very many points.

[image]

Comment: When I follow your solution I get a key error 0 on the x declaration, and when I change it to 1, I get the same error for the -1 index. I'll read the source doc, but if you have any tips on why I might be getting that error, let me know

Comment: @SammyWammy With your real data you might have datetimes, which can complicate getting the proper x. At the very least you can switch to `.iloc` to ensure you grab the first value, something like `ut9_time.iloc[0], ut9_time.iloc[-1]`.

Comment: Yep that was causing that issue since my data is in fact datetime (though as you noted that does not appear necessary otherwise). Only remaining issue is now I'm getting a complain about the datatype "ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')"

Comment: @SammyWammy If you work with the integer representation of times `x = np.linspace(ut9_time[0].value, ut9_time[-1].value, len(ut9_time)*Nfine)` it should work, but then you'll need a way to fix the representation of the values it plots.