# highlight or change plot line color based on y value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code which give the following screenshot.

```
plt.plot(x, y, label = name, linestyle="-")
```

[image: graph]

I would like the line to be highlighted or flashy whenever the y-value is above 0.35.

Does anybody have an idea how I could do that? It doesn't necessarily has to be the color, it could be the line width or the type of line that change, but what I want is to have a visual effect to show that a threshold has been breached.

thanks

Comment: You could have 2 `plt.plot` statements, one for whenever the value is above 3.5 and one for the rest. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Is it possible to change line color in a plot if exceeds a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121773/python-is-it-possible-to-change-line-color-in-a-plot-if-exceeds-a-specific-rang)

Comment: you mean something like this in an if else statement?  # if y > .35:
#     plt.plot(x, y, label = name, linestyle="-")
# else:
#     plt.plot(x, y, label = name, linestyle="--")